# I'm trying to understand recursion? Why is it when I run this code the answer is 13

Tags: java, recursion

```java
public class Test{
    
    public static int sum(int num){
        if (num <= 1){
            return num;
        }
        return 2 + sum(num -1);
        
    }

     public static void main(String []args){
       System.out.print(sum(7));
     }
}
```

I'm trying to understand recursion? Why is it when I run this code the answer is 13?

Comment: What does Python have to do with this?

Comment: Start with the relation `sum(7) = 2 + sum(6)`, which is clear from the method definition. Then figure out the value of `sum(6)`. Continue until you get a number.

Comment: To understand recursion, you must first understand recursion. Just had to say it.

Answer (score 1):

Follow it by hand on paper.  The first thing that happens is `sum(7)`.  That call checks for `num <= 1`, which is false.  So, in order to do the next line, it has to call `sum(6)`.  The original call is pushed on the stack, and we start handling `sum(6)`.  That call also falls through the `if`, and calls `sum(5)`.

Eventually we are nested 7 levels deep:

```
sum(7)
  sum(6)
    sum(5)
      sum(4)
        sum(3)
          sum(2)
            sum(1)
```

Now, in the sum(1) call, `num` is <= 1, so we return 1.  They key is, where do we return?  We return out one level, to the call for sum(2).  Its call to `sum(1)` returned 1.  We add 2 to that and return 3.

Now, we're in the `sum(3)` call.  It got 3, so it returns 5.

Now, we're in the `sum(4)` call.  It got 5, so it returns 7.

And so on.  Eventually, we get to the outer `sum(7)` call.  Its call to `sum(6)` returned 11; it adds 2 and returns 13.

The main function gets 13.

Answer (score 1):

`sum(1)` is 1.
`sum(2)` is `2 + sum(1)`, so it's 3.
`sum(3)` is `2 + sum(2)`, so it's 5.
`sum(4)` is `2 + sum(3)`, so it's 7.
`sum(5)` is `2 + sum(4)`, so it's 9.
`sum(6)` is `2 + sum(5)`, so it's 11.
`sum(7)` is `2 + sum(6)`, so it's 13.